# JPA OneToMany, always empty

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

i have a bidirectional, one to many, and many to one relationship. say, a Company has many Persons, and a Persons has one company, so, in company,

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Person> persons;
```

and in Person,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")
private Company company;
```

now, say i have a @PrePersist / @PreUpdate method on Company, where when it is updated, i want to set the same timestamp on all the People ... like,

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
public void setLastModified() {
    this.lastModified = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (persons != null) {
        for (Person person : persons) {
            person.setLastModified(this.lastModified);
        }
    }
}
```

when i debug this, i see that the persons field in Company is always empty. when i look at the type of the persons collection, it's a java.util.Vector. not sure if that's relevant. i expected to see some auto-loading JPA collection type.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You must set both sides of your relationship.  When you create a new Person and set its Company you must also add the Person to the Company's persons (employees?).

Also, you should not change another object in one object's prePersist/Update, you should use its own prePersist/Update event.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side

Comment: I was going to add my own hack with a rudimentary version of what this link specifies, but I had no idea it was actually an approach suggested by experts.

Answer (score 1):

Add fetch = FetchType.Eager to @ManyToOne annotation. You added it on the other side of relationship.

Comment: thanks. i haven't got a chance to verify this yet, but i will update this question when i do.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this fixed by realizing that I did not need a (Bidirectional) OneToMany - ManyToOne relationship.

For example, in a Unidirectional OneToMany relationship, just write something like:

```
// Company Class:
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();

// Person Class:
// - Remove the 3 lines
```

Check this example:
https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/tree/master/spring-data/spring-data-rest-associations/src/main/java/com/example/demo

**If this does not fix your issue**, check if you are using **Lombok** in your Person or Company classes.

If that is the case, add these two annotations in the Company class (vice-versa for the Person class):

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "persons"}) // This,
@ToString(exclude = { "persons"}) // and this
public class Company implements Serializable {

// ...
private Set<Person> persons = ...
/ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to get`personList` in `Company`, use `FetchType.EAGER`.
In JPA,

```
@--ToOne    =>  Default :  FetchType.EAGER 
@--ToMany   =>  Default :  FetchType.LAZY

@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Company company;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a known bug in Hibernate, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9979.

Unfortunately I am not aware of any workarounds.